# Where does the term HODL come from?

Tags: investing

I know that HODL means you hold your crypto for the long run, whether the price goes up or down, but where does the term come from?

I have heard people say it means "Hold On for Dear Life" and other that it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There term originated as a forum post in December 2013 as - what I can only assume to be a drunk day trader. That is holding his coins as the price is crashing.

I don't think it was intended to mean "Hold On for Dear Life" but it has definitely grown to mean that as OP explains that there are three people, the losers (inexperienced traders) and winners(experienced traders) and the group in the middle that buy and hold on for dear life. The forum post itself is an interesting read and I defz recommend that you check it out yourself: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=375643.0

Answer (score 0):

It originated from this bitcointalk thread, posted in December 2013:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=375643.0

It was a typo, but has since been given the alternative meaning you mentioned.